# UIView, very slowly animating background color, hangs scroll view (!)

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview, core-animation

Here's one, when a certain screen arrives,

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:20 animations:^
        { self.view.backgroundColor =
        [UIColor colorWithHue:0 saturation:0 brightness:0.97 alpha:1];
        }];
```

I want to very slowly, take it from white to soft white.

Bizarrely - if you add this to a view, it crashes any scroll views (table views, collection views) you happen to have there, I think on that view or indeed just anywhere on screen.  (The slow fade works fine!)

Try it on any fullscreen view.

Has anyone noticed this?  Thoughts?   Cheers

PS just incidentally, very slowly going to off-white for the whole screen is a great design look, particularly on retina iPad.  (Breaking any tables is not so good though :O )

Comment: Does it really "crash" or "hang" or is it simply that user interactions is disabled during those 20 seconds?

Comment: David - it goes "super-jerky and irregular" .. you know?  Strange one!

Comment: You could try animating the background color of `view.layer` with `CAAnimation`

Comment: I tried this, and I don't see any problem with my table view if I add the UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction option. Without that, the table view doesn't respond to touches, and a button doesn't either. That's the normal behavior.

Comment: Ah!  perhaps **UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction** is the secret - I simply didn't know about it.  This is awesome, perhaps you should elevate it to an answer, rd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of rdelmar's tip!

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1
    delay:0.0
    options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
    animations:^
    { c.backgroundColor=[[UIColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5];}
    completion:nil
    ];
```